# Problem with multiidimentional input to loop and list

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

First time asking in the forum.

I have a problem.

I have to loop thru a vertical list like this.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

Each separated by enter key, not by space. And then reorganize each item/number descending.

For the descending organization i already know it can be sorted or sorted reverse. But for all I have tried I cannot loop thru all the items in the vertical list.
It only reads 1 and ends the cycle which I understand it is only reading the first list but I just do not know how to loop thru vertical lists be it 1 single value or a matrix.

This is my code

```
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input

numbers = raw_input()
line = []

for row in numbers:
    line.append(row)
    print(line)
line.sort(reverse=True)
for value in line:
    print(value)
```

input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

Once again each separated by enter key, not by space
output:

```
['1']
```

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Do you need to use python 2 or can you use python 3? Why do you import and use `raw_input`?

Comment: Hmmmmmm, I'm using python 3. But sincerely I am a begginer so there's much I don't get. I was using normal input before and the results where the same. I am almost sure I can loop the thru all the items in the input but since is a nested list input my loop only reads 1 line and closes. But yeah about the question I'm not sure if input and raw input do the same.